# Using ifstream to read dynamic data

Tags: c++, file, dynamic, sdl

**--**

**EDIT:** I just realized that the "right" answer to this is maybe a little bit to advance for me at the moment. I want to focus on adding stuff to the game at this moment and not making the best save/load system. I've taken your suggestions and you've opened my mind for loads of great stuff to do in the future. Mainly labeling the data saved (maybe using XML). 
For the moment i'll just add some primitive function to make it work at this stage of development.

**--**

I need some help breaking out a logical and nice way of doing this. It's for a game i'm making  using c++ and SDL. I need some help with the save/load stuff. Basically when i save a game there are some stuff that will always be there (player name, position, gold ect..). But there are also some dynamically saved content, like stats, equipped items and items in the inventory (in the future finished quests will be saved here as well).

I have no problem saving this data down, it's easy. The problem i have is how to structure it's breakpoints when reading the data. This is an example of how a savefile might look:

> CharName (some variables like positions that will always be saved)
>   (the first statMap looks like this "string int" fetched from
>   map) (second statMap, it's the same) (equipped items, one
>   item is split into three parts "string name int ID string
>   description") (items in inventory, the same as the last one)

I hope you understand my example. I'd like some help understanding a logical way to structure this. I'm thinking of maybe ending each dynamic sequence with a char and then load the line up to that char in a string. Then i split that string into several parts. But that sound like an awful amount of steps. Could you help me out?

Comment: get used to the concept of length-prefixed content buffers. Something tells me you'll be using a lot of them shortly.

Comment: Have you thought of using XML to store the data?

Comment: It's easier and less error-prone to first write out the type and length of the following object, rather than using a terminator.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto: I haven't looked into XML, is it preferable? Anyway this is early-early-alpha of the game so this isn't any final touches i am adding.

Comment: @SegFault: So you mean first having something like "stat lenght1 lengh2 <rest of data>"? And when i read in the data i first check how much to read and how to handle it?

Comment: @Tallkotten Yes, then you don't have to guess what the following data is, you read a fixed-length header that gives you the type and length info, and then you already know how to handle the following data.

Comment: @Tallkotten: Based on what you described as your data, XML in my opinion would be the easier way... and would allow you to add/remove fields (new versions of the file) without to much work.

Comment: Basic approach is define persistent structure(Command, object_count, objects) If no items then it will be (ITEMS_SECTION, 0) and parser will see that there are no items and skip this section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very common method for structuring datafiles in games is to use a header and a body: in the header you define the structure of the content in the body based around offsets:

e.g Data for character stats begins at offset 10054, and continues for 2120 characters (you must define and use a standard character size to make this work).

Then when you read it you read the header to get the structure, and then load the data from the areas that it specifies.

Comment: <header>stat</header>
<body>atkdmg 100 movespeed 200 ect...</body>

Something like that? A previous comment recommended using XML, i looked into it and i think i'm going to use it in the future just not at this moment since i want to focus on other stuff at the moment.

Comment: no, more like <header>210,10,220,75,305,134,432,40</header> where these numbers mean: first bit of data starts at 210 and continues for 10 chars (or bytes, or whatever you use). The next bit of data starts at 220 and continues for 75. The next bit begins at 305 and continues for 134, etc etc. These locations are further down in the file, i.e in the "body" and in these locations is the data you need.

Comment: XML is a fine option as well. But by rolling your own you can make it faster and smaller because you don't need the XML tags. If you're planning on loading huge amounts of data (e.g art asset vertex and texture data) then this can be worth doing.

Comment: @Tallkotten For a start you might want to stay with binary, which is far easier to parse (and far memory-friendlier) than XML. Data files (especially 3D models and images) are not meant to be read by mere humans anyway.

Comment: In the header you can add a code number that means "type" as well if you like.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good. I will probably end up doing something myself when i get to that point. Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: @Tallkotten Good luck with your game! If you ask another question about your saving and loading system (or come back and edit this one) I suggest you include code showing us your data structures so we know what data you're trying to save/load. Then we can provide code samples that'll iterate through it and save it in a readable format. Without that all we can do is suggest broad ideas.